# Android App Service with android:isolatedProcess="true" not working with intune SDK

Tags: android, aidl, android-service-binding, intune

**Describe the bug:**

I have an app which uses Intune SDK for android. We want to integrate a service with with `android:isolatedProcess="true"` for root detection related functionality on our App.
But, android Service with **android:isolatedProcess="true"** not able to work with our App with already integrated Intune SDK.

**We have also tried to create an separate sample App with Intune and with a service having set `android:isolatedProcess` in Manifest. But this service is not working.**

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Create a sample app with service having set `android:isolatedProcess` in Manifest. Declaration in manifest is as below:

```
<service
        android:name=".RemoteService"
        android:useAppZygote="true"
        android:isolatedProcess="true" />
```

2. We are using `bindService` method to bind to the service. As shown below:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,IsolatedService.class);
    /*Binding to an isolated service */
    getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, mIsolatedServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

3. When running this sample, it is able to connect to isolated process and `onServiceConnected()` method of `ServiceConnection` is called.
4. Then we have integrated the Intune library with this App.
5. When running sample app after integrating Intune SDK, it is not able to run the service having set `android:isolatedProcess.`

You can integrate Intune SDK and can check with these existing app which have isolated process to check this scenario: [MagiskDetector](https://github.com/vvb2060/MagiskDetector)
OR
[DetectMagiskHide](https://github.com/darvincisec/DetectMagiskHide)

**Expected behavior:**

It's expected that service with `android:isolatedProcess` flag set work normally with App which have already Intune SDK integrated. Isolated process do work with Intune SDK for Android App.

**logs:**

If your app is not experiencing an issue during build: **There is no logs at build time.**

If your app is experiencing an issue post build? : **App is not crashing so, Android studio not shows any logs.**

**Smartphone:**
It's an issue on all devices. I have checked it on Redmi note 3 (Android M) and POCO f1 (Android 11 Q)

**Intune App SDK for Android:**

What version of the Intune SDK are you using? : **We are using latest version : Version 7.6.0**

What platform is your app based in (Java, Xamarin based, Cordova, etc)? : **App is based in Java.**

Do you see a trend with it only being reproduced on a specific device? : **No there is no trend. It's not working on any device.**

**Questions**

1. **Can we run isolated process with Intune SDK on Android App?**
2. **Is there any workaround/solution to use isolated process with Intune SDK?**

You can find more here: [Android Service with android:isolatedProcess="true" not working with intune SDK.](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-android/issues/76)